# Relativistic photoelectric effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect, doppler-effect

Suppose, one conducted an experiment with a monochromatic light shining on a metal plate with a certain work function. It turns out the electron is ejected. When this experiment is observed by another frame, so that the observed frequency of the light is lower than the cutoff, the electron is not ejected. Is there anything wrong with these arguments?

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, but just to give you something to go off of: The electron is ejected in *both* frames. Both observers should agree about this. If there is a detector rigged to set off an explosion when an electron is detected, then both observers must either see the explosion, or not see the explosion.

Comment: The cutoff frequency is relative and will be lower in the other frame.

Comment: By the way, you don't even need special relativity to get this "paradox". You already have a it because of the classical Doppler effect.